# C++ Beginner Q (volume of box)

Tags: c++

I am working on a basic C++ program to find the volume of a box. My problem is that the program does not prompt the user for input for the variables l, w , and h. Here is the complete code so far.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int l;
   int w;
   int h;
   int vol;

   cout << "Length: \n";
   cin >> l;

   cout << "Width: \n";
   cin >> w;

   cout << "Height: \n";
   cin >> h;

   vol = l * w * h;
   cout << "Volume: " << vol << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

This is the output that I see

```
Length:
Width:
Height:
Volume: 0
```

The program does not allow for input after each line. It just runs the whole thing.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't prompt the user? That's what your `cout`s are doing.

Comment: Could not repro in VS2015 Update 3, program works as expected. What compiler are you using?

Comment: looks pretty ok to me, though I'd recommend breaking the habit of importing all std early.

Comment: Works just fine [here](http://ideone.com/FLZW1Y)?

Comment: How are you running the program? It looks like it isn't connected to a terminal for stdin.

Comment: @Borgleader Sorry guys, I'm very new to this. I would like the program to ask for inputs one at a time. So it would ask for "Length: " and then the user can input a number, and so on for the other 2 variables. Also I am taking an online class and it is a web-based compiler so that could be part of the problem. Thanks for your quick responses.

Comment: @AlexA If it's a web based compiler (like I have used in my link), you should probably specify the inputs in advanced (as I did there). Here's [another example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab0dd98c88b94485) for coliru.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think that solved my problem. Thank you so much. Is there any way to make it ask for inputs one at a time with a web based compiler?

Comment: @AlexA Depends what you're using (forced to use). E.g. [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/) supports that.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine for me. Are you compiling it correctly? (And are you sure you're not compiling an old version of the file before you added the cin's?)

Compile it with this command:

```
g++ my_file.cpp
```

or, if you're using clang:

```
clang++ my_file.cpp
```

To run it, simply type:

```
./a.out
```

You should then get all your prompts (which are the cin's):

```
Length:
3
Width:
4
Height:
5
Volume: 60
```

Comment: Well, it turned out that OP had a completely different problem. Read the commnets at the question.